# Read CSV file in Matlab to matrix

Tags: matlab, csv, matrix, nan

I need to read a CSV file in Matlab. That file is mostly numeric (except the first column, and it has actually 178 columns) and has missing values, denoted by NA . Here's two rows for example :

> 24-MAR-2005  , 2.145202 , 2.192237 , 2.238725 , 2.284657 , 2.330028 , 2.374829 , 2.419056 , ...
>
> 25-MAR-2005  ,NA        ,NA        ,NA        ,NA        ,NA        ,NA        ,NA        , ...

I would like to read those NA's as NaN's and convert the overall to a matrix but I can't get it done properly.

On a side note, I don't really need the dates (the first column that is).

Here's what I've tried:

```
filename = 'foo.csv';
fid = fopen(filename,'rt');
[data]=textscan(fid, '%s %f' , 178,'delimiter',',',...
                                   'TreatAsEmpty','NA',...
                                   'EmptyValue', NaN);
```

Comment: I have tried to scan, treat empty the 'NA''s and setting the empty value to NaN this way

filename = 'foo.csv';

fid = fopen(filename,'rt');

[data]=textscan(fid, '%s %f' , 178,'delimiter',',','TreatAsEmpty','NA', 'EmptyValue', NaN);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the date with `%*s` but you need to specify 178 `%f` and the delimiter:

```
textscan(fid, ['%*s' repmat('%f',1,178)],'Delimiter',',','CollectOutput',true)
```

Comment: Thank you! this, combined with what I already tried, works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I'll offer this up, but it's not much

```
% read in the entire file
fid = fopen('tmp.csv');
A = fread(fid);
% convert to a character array
B = char(A)';
% create a cell array with one element for every line in the file
lineData = regexp(B,'\n','split');
% for every line in the data, parse out all the data into a
% cell array
data = cell(1,length(lineData));
for ii=1:length(lineData)
  pData = textscan(lineData{ii},'%s','Delimiter',',');
  % remove any spaces from the elements
  data{ii} = cellfun(@(x) strrep(x,' ',''), pData{1},'UniformOutput',false);
end
```